# How to fixed a <Text> in a scrollView?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

My all screen has a scrollView, and there's a  in the middle of it. I want when someone scroll up, the text be fixed at the top and does not disappear. How can I do that? I didn't find it anywhere, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={{ position : 'absolute', textAlign: 'center'}}>
    Special Text
    </Text>
    <ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

you can do something like this

Comment: I can't because there is something above the text and it has to scroll up

Answer (score 0):

Use css property position: sticky. that will fixed your text at the top it's called sticky position. So, Please read it https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_sticky

Be patient.

Cheer you!

Comment: It said, "sticky was not defined" in my styles js

Comment: it said its too long

Comment: <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View style={styles.viewVerticalScroll}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Promoções</Text>

Comment: I want this <Text> fixed at the top

Comment: Here <Text style={styles.title}> put the position : sticky. I don't know about that how to be need put in If you using dynamic value so put the position in you object, json... and get the value <Text style={styles.position}> as well

Comment: it said 'sticky' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to implement something similar and i got it done but unfortunately it is kinda complex (relatively) at least compared to what you would do on the web. it requires using the onLayout prop.

```
state = {zIndex: 0};

<View>
  <View style={[your_style, {position: "relative", zIndex: this.state.zIndex}]} onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => {this.outTextHeight = nativeEvent.layout.height}}>
    <Text>Special Text</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{[your_style, {zIndex: 1}]}>
    <ScrollView onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {if(nativeEvent.contentOffset.y >= (this.insideTextHeight + this.insideTextOffsety){this.setState({zIndex: 2})})}}>
      // your content
      <View onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => {this.insideTextHeight = nativeEvent.layout.height; this.insideTextOffsety = nativeEvent.layout.y}}>// this maybe the same height so may be unnecessary
        <Text>Special Text</Text>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</View>
```